# Jenkins workspace is deleted after sometimes

Tags: git, jenkins, fetch, workspace

In general, Jenkins builds are well done. But Sometimes, build is failed and workspace is deleted. here is error log. my jenkins version is 2.193 and gitplugin version is 3.0.1

```
Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on buildServer in workspace D:\Jenkins\workspace\GB>
 C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
ERROR: Workspace has a .git repository, but it appears to be corrupt.
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1752)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1718)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1714)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1385)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommand(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1397)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.hasGitRepo(CliGitAPIImpl.java:196)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.hasGitRepo(GitAPI.java:232)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:887)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:862)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:821)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" (in directory "D:\Jenkins\workspace\GB"): CreateProcess error=5, 엑세스가 거부되었습니다
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:243)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1741)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, 엑세스가 거부되었습니다
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repositoryhttps://github.com/(repository)
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init D:\Jenkins\workspace\GB # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/(repository)
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials GB jenkins account
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags https://github.com/(repository) t +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Error performing command: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags https://github.com/(repository) +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1752)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1489)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:512)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to buildserver_200(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1433)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:253)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:797)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1054)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1094)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" (in directory "D:\Jenkins\workspace\GB"): CreateProcess error=5, 엑세스가 거부되었습니다
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:243)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1741)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1489)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:64)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:315)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:512)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:332)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, 엑세스가 거부되었습니다
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
ERROR: null
Discard old builds...
#232 is removed because old than numToKeep
Warning: ��Access Control for Builds�� in global security configuration is empty, so falling back to legacy behavior of permitting any downstream builds to be triggered
Finished: FAILURE
```

when i face this this issue, i have to copy repository. because workspace is completely deleted even .git folder.
is it git plugin error? is there a way to resolve?

Comment: Could you please tell me what are the steps that you have configured in this job?

Comment: @VighneshPai first, git checkout to specific local branch and inject environment variables and execute windows batch command. but when jenkins is git step, checkout is failed.

Comment: where have you hosted the jenkins? is it on the cloud? like amazon instance?

Comment: I guess the workspace is corrupted, so try cleaning the workspace as a part of pre build step or a post build step.